# Has Azerbaijan announced plans to repopulate Khankendi (formerly Stepanakert)?

Tags: azerbaijan

There was a bunch of reporting from Stepanakert-cum-Khankendi a month ago, showing it virtually devoid of population, since the Armenians practically all fled.

I alas could find any news in English what the Azerbaijani government might be planning for the city in longer run. I recall reading at the time they were mainly concerned with restoring power/gas and policing, in the immediate aftermath. Have the Azerbaijani authorities announced plans to repopulate the city, somehow?

I was able to find out they [held](https://apnews.com/article/azerbaijan-military-parade-karabakh-aliyev-armenia-2b7e1c12175c6d02f4564e9c014aa282) victory parade in the city, this month, but not much else.

Comment: After the 2020 war they did announce a plan for those territories (recovered then) although that was apparently main infrastructure https://eurasianet.org/azerbaijan-starts-rebuilding-in-newly-won-territories So, I suspect the answer for 2023 is or will be yes, but I can't find anything in English.

Comment: Arte reportage about the towns repopulated after 2020 https://youtu.be/eUldgjS-48s?t=455 Less clear how that would work for Khankendi, because in those prior cases the Azerbaijani government apparently moved refugees back to where they had fled from.

Answer (score 2):

According to [haqqin.az](https://m.haqqin.az/news/300977):

> Azerbaijan plans to return more than 140 thousand former internally
> displaced persons to Karabakh and Eastern Zangezur by the end of 2026.
> This is stated in the address of President Ilham Aliyev to the
> participants of the ministerial session of the 5th Conference of Labor
> Ministers of the member countries of the Organization of Islamic
> Cooperation in Baku.
>
> “Currently, large-scale restoration work is being carried out in our
> liberated territories, and important infrastructure projects are being
> implemented.
>
> As part of the Great Return program, former internally displaced
> persons have already returned to the lands of their fathers and
> grandfathers - to the cities of Lachin and Fuzuli, including three
> villages. By the end of 2026, more than 140 thousand people are
> expected to return to Karabakh and Eastern Zangezur,” the head of
> state said in his address.

Comment: Somewhat useful. They had such a program after the 2020 victory too. It's less clear what that entails for Khankendi in particular though.

Comment: Their previous plan didn't involve any human transfers, because they thought people would be unwilling to leave their homes to come to place with limited infrastructure. Now the situation changed ...

Comment: Did I receive bounty for this or nah...?

Comment: Apparently only 25, and not +50 as promised

Comment: Well, it was a half-answer.

Comment: Was it? It was a yes-no question